# How to fix shapeAssertionError while using combineReducer in redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am getting an error while using combineReducer method in redux (redux@3.7.2). Same code will work when I am using only one reducer.

[Running code here](https://repl.it/repls/RingedAnotherCodewarrior)

**Code**

```
const { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } = require ('redux')

const aReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'A':
            {
                return { ...state };
            }
        default: return state;
    }
    return state;
}

const bReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'B':
            {
                return { ...state };
            }
        default: return state;
    }
    return state;
}

const configureStore = (initialState) => {


    let rootReducer = combineReducers({ a:aReducer, b:bReducer });
    console.log('configureStore', initialState);
    const str = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
    return str;
};


const store = configureStore({});

console.log('store',store);

store.subscribe(() => {

    console.log(store.getState());

});
```

In the create store line, if i am replacing the rootReducer to aReducer, this code wont have any problem. I did not understand why the reducers returning undefined state, i am passing initial state as a plane object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here. Firstly, `combineReducers` also combines the states of each reducer in an object with the same keys as the argument reducers object, so to initialize each state correctly you'll need:

```
const store = configureStore({a: {}, b: {}});
```

This is not enough to fix the problem though, as `combineReducers` also requires that each reducer can handle state `undefined` and never returns `undefined`
([see the docs](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers#notes)). If it can't you get this error:

```
Error: Reducer "..." returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the
reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may
not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null
instead of undefined.
```

The confusing thing about this is that the check is done when `combineReducers` is called (ie. before state initialization,) but the error isn't shown until the reducer is used. This means that even if you initialize the state correctly, and your reducers never receive state `undefined`, you'll still get the error if the reducers can't handle it.

To fix it, replace `(state, action) => {` in each reducer by `(state = {}, action) => {`, or explicitly return `null` if `state` is `undefined`. Note that these initial states are only used if you don't pass an initial state to `createStore`. To prevent confusion, I usually do all initialization in the reducers and not at `createStore`.

Comment: How could we manage this if I wanted to load initial state from local storage?

Comment: In that case it makes sense to use `createStore` for state initialization; just remember to also provide a dummy initial state for each reducer (which is overridden by the `createStore` initial state.)